# XSLT transformation results in characters at the beginning of the document

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have an xml doc like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfApiFeedProduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ApiFeedProduct>
      <Code>C119X</Code>
      <OfferCode>MJF*Q*MJ*13</OfferCode>
      <ProductType>Straight</ProductType>
      <Title>Joseph Perrier Cuvée Royale Brut Champagne</Title>
      <SDesc>Joseph Perrier Cuvée Royale Brut Champagne</SDesc>...
```

And an XSLT doc like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <add>
      <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfApiFeedProduct/ApiFeedProduct">
        <doc>
          <field name="code">
            <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
          </field>
          <field name="offercode">
            <xsl:value-of select="OfferCode"/>
          </field>
          <field name="producttype">
            <xsl:value-of select="ProductType"/>
          </field>
          <field name="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
          </field>
          <field name="sdesc">
            <xsl:value-of select="SDesc"/>
          </field>...
```

But this results in an xml document like

```
��<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<add>
<doc>
<field name="code">C119X</field>
<field name="offercode">MJF*Q*MJ*13</field>
<field name="producttype">Straight</field>
<field name="title">Joseph Perrier Cuvée Royale Brut Champagne</field>
<field name="sdesc">Joseph Perrier Cuvée Royale Brut Champagne</field>...
```

Where do the first two characters come from?? i.e. ��?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect they make up the Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) encoded as UTF-8.  If your document is considered well-formed by a conforming XML processor, then that likely guarantees it, as any other characters before the XML Declaration would render the file not well-formed.